# GWT Designer, .ui.xml files

Tags: gwt, web-applications, gwt-designer

Question is about Google GWT Designer. GWT Designer can work with .java files without any .ui.xml files. But I have a gwt project where design is realized with .ui.xml files and java classes. It more complex then just java class. Do you heve any ideas what is it? May be it should be refactorized?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly there's no need to refactor ready made UiBinder if it written well. This's a great GWT framework allowing separation of logic from view. If you reject it your project will be very difficult to maintain.

Secondly one and the same GWT project can contain the view implemented both in Java code and in UiBinder xml files. This situation occurs with a support of old projects where UiBinder wasn't yet. Uibinder is a much more modern approach which has many benefits. That is if you for some reason prefer declare view only in Java code without xml then write it in Java code. And this will coexist and work properly.

And most importantly present-day GWT Designer has [support](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/wizards/gwt/uibinder_composite) UiBinder. Otherwise, no one would use it.

Comment: You can read more about Ui:Binder here:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

I have another question. See exanple of code please: [http://snipt.org/vhhC5](http://snipt.org/vhhC5). What is purpose of interface MoviesViewDisplay from example?

Thanks!

Comment: Just some interface defining methods are required to implement by the custom widget. Its functionality is resemble to the interface [HasWidgets](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasWidgets.html). I think it made ​​sense to extend it.